# I am using Searchkit version 2.4.4 I need to be able to search with a daterangeFilter. It's not working with my versions of react

Tags: reactjs

I have an old react-app that used searchkit and a daterangefilter implemented through searchkit-datefilter. I now have a newer version of react and it is not compatible. How would I be able to get the same functionality of searching with a daterangefilter component and a calendar component.

This is the code that I had previously

```
   <DateRangeFilter
                        id="date"
                        title="Date Range"
                        fromDateField="postDate"
                        toDateField="postDate"
                        calendarComponent={DateRangeCalendar}
                    />
```